# testing blog locally?

Tags: html, css, localhost, blogger

I have a blogger template (xml file). Is there any way to test or run the blogger theme locally?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot build them offline. You can only preview/test/build them in the live Blogger system.

[Here is a great article](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/the-web-designers-guide-to-blogger-templates/) that addresses that among a ton of other factors.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to hack a local test together with Firefox Web Developer Plugin + FireBug extension (modify the website code locally).

The easier way: a sample blog to test it?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, you should be able to perform a preview of your template from within blogger, but maybe that was with old-style templates?

Answer (score -1):

The only way to test the templates is using a test blog ready all the time.
Not a cool way though but works.
Searching for a different way and didn't got one.